# javascript math, list, and click feature

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/mGGPu/

What I am trying to do is when clicked on the Select Button, the item name will go into cart as well as the price of the item. Then when adding more items, javascript will do the math of the overall "price" owed.

Also would want, after clicking the button it becomes disabled.

```
<div class="itemWrapper">
   <div id="item1" class="item">
      <span class="title">Item 1</span><br />
      <span class="image"><img src="http://www.thinkgeek.com/images/products/zoom/tqualizer_anim.gif" /></span><br />
      <div class="descrip">
         <span class="points">1000 pts</span><span class="sale">ON SALE</span><br />
         <span class="description">Here would be a simple description of the item for sale. 
         Then We will create a button below.</span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <input type="submit" class="button2" value="Add To Cart" />
</div>
<div class="cartWrapper" />
<div class="cart" id="cartj">
   <div class="cart_body">
      <div class="cart_title">Shopping Cart</div>
      <div class="cart_items">
         <ul>
            <li></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me? Not sure if this code was the best to use

```
$('.button2').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.title').css("color","red");
});
```

That was just testing the click of button and to change the title color. That was just a test code, kind of like a follow through to see if the click function was working. Though it didn't.

Maybe this for making the item go into cart?

```
(function($){
$(function(){ $('.button2').click(function();var   
 innerTxt=$(this).text();innerTxt=$.trim(innerTxt);var $obj=
 $('.cart_items li');$obj.val($obj.val()+innerTxt);})}); })(jQuery);​​​
```

Though its not complete. I'm running on like no sleep, and am brain dead today.

Comment: What have you tried? I'm not seeing any javascript that attempts to do anything.

Comment: You might as well try to use JavaScript to build a house. There are so many things involved in building an effective online shopping cart that you aren't even thinking about yet.

Comment: Its not really a shopping cart. We will call this a dummyCart. It will not process any data or anything of that sorts. Its just an online RPG cart for spending points. Points have to be deducted manually at the site. This is just a rough sketch for people to see how much they owe.

Comment: and oh Ive never used jQuery for math...I don't even know the name for it? .math???

Comment: edited the first post, added a jQuery code for items

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the span inside the Div..

Span with class `title` is not a ancestor of the button. It is a sibling. So you need to traverse to the button's parent and find th`e title` you are looking for.

```
$('.button2').on('click', function() {

  $(this).closest('.itemWrapper').find('.title').css("color","red");
});
```

[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/mGGPu/1/)

Comment: Thank you, I thought so. I tried div.itemWrapper span.title like that in the closest. I knew I skipped a step there. though I'm not going actually change the .css of the title. I'm actually going to use this code to added to the cart.